# Clarity on Safe Navigation Operator in Angular

Tags: angular

[Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) says:

> Sometimes however, null values in the property path may be OK under
> certain circumstances, especially when the value starts out null but
> the data arrives eventually.
>
> With the safe navigation operator, ?, Angular stops evaluating the
> expression when it hits the first null value and renders the view
> without errors.

I'm finding little ambiguity over here. Does it say that using *Safe Navigation Operator* will not render (update) data which was `null` at first but eventually got changed say because of AJAX call updated that object after some time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it says that using Safe Navigation Operator will not
>   render(update) data which was null at first but eventually got changed
>   say because of AJAX call updated that object after some time?

No. It means that the expression is not evaluated after it detects some `null` value (but won't stop from rendering if it changes in the future to some non-null value).

For example if in *component.ts* you have

```
val = null;
// ...
someService.someMethod().susbcribe(val => this.val);
```

and in the *component.html* you have

```
{{val?.someProperty}}
```

Initially nothing will be rendered because `val` is `null`.

Now, once some value arrives inside the `susbcribe` and `this.val` gets some non-null value, the value of `val.someProperty` is rendered in the view.

See a **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-safe-navigator-operator?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)** using a timeout.

Comment: One more issue: in my case `course` object is `undefined`, template expression `{{ cardIndex + course?.description }}` evaluates to `1` for first item which is correct. But, for `{{ cardIndex + ' ' + course?.description }}`, why does it evaluate to `1 null`?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my last comment. I assume it is because the string contatenation. This should work: `{{ cardIndex }} {{ course?.description }}`

Comment: But, my doubt is why next part is evaluating if it is `undefined`. And why it is `1 null` and not `1 undefined` if it is string concatenation?

Comment: @GeniusGo that's interesting, yes. Right now I'm in the middle of something here and won't be able to read more about this. But I'll be back to this whenever I get a chance. If you find the answer to this curious case, please share it here :)

Comment: Sure, @lealceldeiro. I will also explore for it. Thanks for showing interest! :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, be very careful when using the safe navigation operator in an 'if' clause, when you are trying to evaluate whether an object property exists or not.

If you have a boolean, as a property value, and it is false, the program won't execute inside the 'if' clause, like:

```
const data = {
 showProducts  = false;
};

if( data?.showProducts ){
 ...
}
```

If you want to see if a property exists or not, use:

```
if( 'showProducts' in data ){
 ...
}
```

The safe navigation operator definitely has its uses, but just be careful when using it, with **falsey** values.

I probably could have lest this *answer* as a *comment*. but I am sick and tired of not being able to format my comments.